# MDriven Server installation

Tags: mdriven

I have tried to install `MDriven Server` and `MDriven Turnkey` locally by following [this](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Installing_MDriven_Server) guide.

But when I tried to run my MDriven Turnkey app I've got an unexpected error: [check the CurrentVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NlKo.jpg)

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually looks like you have succeeded with the installation. But if you do not have any model in the MDrivenServer it will hive you the message "Check Current version".

Register a user in MDrivenUser - use MDrivenDesigner to upload a model to it the server - after that you should have a CurrentVersion set.