# "Installing MDriven Server on Windows" - cannot access local Turnkey

Tags: mdriven

I have tried to install MDriven Server and Turnkey according to the page "Installing MDriven Server on Windows" (https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Installing_MDriven_Server_on_Windows) and the Video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=722&v=q0ppL5sMPGg).
Installed versions are MDrivenServer_20190411.zip and MDrivenTurnkey_20190415.zip

The PC is a Windows 2019 Server (also tried on Windows 10 Workstation, results are identical!).

I can open the MDriven Server pages (https://*MyServer*/MyTurnkeyApp/__MDrivenServer) everything looks fine, i.e.:

- I created a new "a" user with a known PWD according to the Video
- DB connectivity/check/evolve is fine
- https/Self-signed SSL certificate works as expected

MDrivenServer works as expected and as described in the article & video!

However I cannot go to the Turnkey pages (https://*MyServer*/MyTurnkeyApp).

I always get an error message:

Server Error in '/MyTurnkeyApp' Application.
Not able to start, check the CurrentVersion - is it set? Check that the app is Started and not Paused. Check that the Version is in DatabaseUpdated state.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Not able to start, check the CurrentVersion - is it set? Check that the app is Started and not Paused. Check that the Version is in DatabaseUpdated state.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Exception: Not able to start, check the CurrentVersion - is it set? Check that the app is Started and not Paused. Check that the Version is in DatabaseUpdated state.]
   AppCompleteGeneric.ACApplication.GetStartedAndRunningFromDatabaseIdentity(EcoSpace adminEcoSpace, DatabaseIdentity databaseIdentity) in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\AppCompleteGeneric\AppCompleteGeneric.Model\AppCompleteGeneric\ACApplication.cs:51
   TurnKeyEcoSpaceWithModelFromServer.TurnKeyEcoSpaceCreator.GetBlank(String databaseID) in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\StreamingApp\StreamingAppGenericAPIAndControllers\TurnKeyEcoSpaceCreator.cs:115
   TurnKeyEcoSpaceWithModelFromServer.TurnKeyEcoSpaceCreator.BorrowEcoSpace(EcoSpaceRequestInfo requestInfo) in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\StreamingApp\StreamingAppGenericAPIAndControllers\TurnKeyEcoSpaceCreator.cs:289
   Eco.MVC.EcoController`1.EnsureEcoSpace(String shelfKey) in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\Eco\Eco.MVC\EcoController.cs:408
   Eco.MVC.EcoController`1.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\Eco\Eco.MVC\EcoController.cs:549
   Eco.MVC.ModelDrivenControllerBase`1.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in c:\capableobjectsbuild2017\source\Eco\Eco.MVC\ModelDrivenControllerBase.cs:97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32 filterIndex) +261
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +333
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +463
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +906
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +711
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +93
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +522
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1020
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer: [MDriven Server installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486563/mdriven-server-installation)
I think it is the same issue.

- You have no model uploaded to mdriven server
- or the model is not selected as current
- or the app slot A0 is not started in mdriven server.